# Why do I never see fighter jets on sites like FlighRadar24 and ADBSExchange.com

Tags: military, fighter, faa, transponder, online-tracking

On ADS-B Exchange they even have a filter option for military aircraft, and it will show all kinds of transport, mid-air refuelers, helicopters, and even training aircraft like the Texan, but I don't think I ever see fighter jets on there. Even when I see some F/A-18s fly overhead IRL I still never see them show up on any websites. Or like right now I noticed that Air Force 1 was flying out of Palm Beach I think it was but I didn't see any fighter escorts show up. Are fighters allowed to just turn off their transponders in civilian airspace?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do flight tracking websites also track non-commercial and defense aircraft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/11814/do-flight-tracking-websites-also-track-non-commercial-and-defense-aircraft)

Answer (score 2):

Because they don't want to be seen.

> Are fighters allowed to just turn off their transponders in civilian airspace?

FR24 and ADS-B Ex are not based on normal transponders (that would require access to actual RADAR data) but rather ADS-B and mode-S transponders. The military can simply choose not to operate with this equipment. This does **not** make the fighters invisible on normal ATC radars, since ATC obviously still needs to be able to see them.

Comment: Flightradar24 has access to [North American radars](https://www.flightradar24.com/how-it-works), which of course blocks the details of military planes. Saw a bunch of planes landing recently at an AFB, all blocked, and then there was the Israeli F-35 [that went live](https://theaviationist.com/2018/07/24/f-35-stealth-aircraft-goes-live-on-flight-tracking-websites-as-it-flies-mission-over-israel/), and also [this teasing](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/37479/14897).